# dynamically update data from excel to existing powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I'm still searching for the right way to solve this. I've tried many ways and it still won't work and I even try to manipulate some code but still won't work

- I already have a bunch of data from Excel dashboard
- I already have a Powerpoint that includes the charts
- I need to update the data from Excel, and the chart in the Powerpoint can update dynamically

Comment: Are you trying to link data updates or chart formatting updates?

Comment: i'm trying to update the data

Comment: What version of Excel / PowerPoint are you using? What have you tried so far? What errors / behaviours are you seeing? You need to provide more information if you want a constructive answer.

Comment: It also isn't clear how you want to data to flow. For example does your Excel dashboard "feed" data directly to the Escel sheets embedded in your powerpoint charts? More detail is needed

Comment: i'm using office 2007.i'm not good in vba code so i dont really understand the syntax been used. im starting from scratch.

Comment: example i have dashboard1 and also powerpoint1.i have to make sure that if dashboard1 is update, all the charts in the powerpoint1 will also updating.some say i should use pastespecial and also linking but i dont sure how it works.

Comment: Well you can do paste special - linking without VBA. If you aren't clear on how you want to achieve this then this isn't really a question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be accomplished without any extra coding. If you just create your chat in Excel, copy it and paste it into PowerPoint it will be linked to the original source data. Be sure to paste it as a `Microsoft Office Graphic Object`. Now, any changed made in Excel will be reflected in PowerPoint.

you can maintain this link by either

- Right click > Reset to Match Style
- Office Button > Prepare > Edit Links to Files

Comment: but then if i close the powerpoint and save it, after i open it again it can't update anymore

Comment: really thanks for the info brad!hope it will satisfied my bos

Comment: No problemo. If it did work for you though be sure to mark this as your accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw I work in excel 2010 and choosing the paste option "keep source formatting & live feed" does the trick

Comment: I dont see any option to have live feed... Could you please tell me where this option is there